# Java generics: List<Container<?>> = new LinkedList<Container<Double>>() is prohibited?

Tags: java, generics

How come, in Java, I can write

```
List<?> list = new LinkedList<Double>();
```

but not

```
List<Container<?>> list = new LinkedList<Container<Double>>();
```

where Container is just something like

```
public class Container<T> { ... }
```

This came up because I have a method that accepts a `List<Container<?>>`, and I would like to use Arrays.asList to pass arguments to it:

```
process(Arrays.asList(new Container<Double>(), new Container<Double>()));
```

But the language doesn't allow this, because it infers the type of `Arrays.asList` to be `List<Container<Double>>`, and that is not assignable to `List<Container<?>>`.

If I add a String-parameterized Container to the call,

```
process(Arrays.asList(new Container<Double>(), new Container<String>()));
```

it still doesn't work, because it infers the type `List<Container<? extends Serializable & Comparable<?>>>` for Arrays.asList. Only if I pass in something that is neither Comparable nor Serializable does it work properly.

Of course, I can put in a cast and get the compiler to shut up, but I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Each parameterization must be wildcarded:

```
List<? extends Container<?>> list = new LinkedList<Container<Double>>();
```

Edit: I was searching through [Angelika Langer's FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) for an explanation, but didn't find one (it's probably there, but hiding somewhere in the 500 pages).

The way to think about this is that each parameterization is independent, and the compiler will not infer information about the parameterization unless you explicitly say to do so.

Answer (score 2):

> Edit: I was searching through Angelika Langer's FAQ for an explanation, but didn't find one (it's probably there, but hiding somewhere in the 500 pages).

Thank you very much for the answer. I found an explanation in the FAQ, and after some squinting at it I think I get it.

http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#What%20do%20multilevel%20wildcards%20mean?

Answer (score 2):

Consider what would happen if you could.

```
List<Container<Double>> list1 = new LinkedList<Container<Double>>();
List<Container<?>> list2 = list1; // this shouldn't be allowed, because of the below
Container<String> foo = new Container<String>();
foo.add("hi");
list2.add(foo); // legal, because Container<String> is a subtype of Container<?>
Container<Double> bar = list1.get(0);
Double x = bar.get(0); // type error; it is actually a String object
                       // this indicates that type safety was violated
```

However, using `List<? extends Container<?>>` doesn't have this problem because you cannot put anything (except `null`) into a list of this type (because there is no type that is guaranteed to be a subtype of "`? extends Container<?>`").