# Why does ArrayList<ArrayList<?>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>() not compile?

Tags: java, generics

Why does this code compile

```
final ArrayList<?> dp1 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

But this doesn't

```
final ArrayList<ArrayList<?>> dp2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/440262/630384

Comment: The 'why' is a little more complicated. But, this will compile: ___final ArrayList<? extends List<?>> dp2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();___

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In

```
final ArrayList<?> dp1 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The type argument `?` is a wildcard which is a superset (not super-type) of `String`. So, `ArrayList<?>` is super type of `ArrayList<String>`.

But in

```
final ArrayList<ArrayList<?>> dp2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

The type argument `ArrayList<?>` (a parameterized type where `?` just stands for some unkown type, and doesn't have anything to do with `String`) is not a wildcard, the wildcard would be `? extends ArrayList<?>`, with an upper bound `ArrayList<?>`, which actually is a supertype of `ArrayList<String>`.

You can read about the rules regarding super/sub set/type in parameterized type [here](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ208).

Answer (score 6):

It's quite complicated to understand, but in summary in your first code, `String` extends `?` but the second one doesn't compile because `ArrayList<String>` does not directly inherit from `ArrayList<?>` you can look [here](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#FAQ104) if you want all the details.
If you want your second example to compile you have to modify it to this :

```
final ArrayList<? extends ArrayList<?>> dp2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

Comment: Does it imply - if I have `class P { }` and `class C extends P { }` then I can do `ArrayList<P> a = new ArrayList<C>();`?